# Looking for meal-planning / grocery list software

Tags: organization, software

I'm looking for software (either PC-based, or web-based) that can be used for meal planning and generating shopping lists. What I'd like is for it to store recipes that I have, including their ingredients. At the beginning of the week, I would like to select recipes and side dishes for dinners and have it generate a shopping list of things necessary for those recipes. A nice feature would be for it to calculate calories, fat content, etc., for the week.

Is there such a thing out there?

Thanks.

Comment: If you happen to be vegetarian/vegan, vegweb.com includes a similar feature; you can save recipes found on the site and then generate a grocery list. (but not quite what you want because AFAIK you can't directly add your own recipes (without going through the normal recipe submission/mod review process, which takes a while))

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I am the owner of the company behind this service as well as the programmer of it.

Except for calculating nutritional data, http://bechamel.net does exactly this, if you are a registered user (which is free). Please note that there's not a whole lot of activity on the rest of the site though, and because of that, there's not a lot of development going on (that doesn't mean there are any plans to shut it down, there's not).

To use Béchamel for this, go to a recipe, click "I want to eat this soon", drag the recipe to the applicable day, go to the shopping list, and add the recipe. You can adjust servings either per recipe in the list, or globally in your profile. It will even coalesce equivalent ingredients in the shopping list (2 eggs in one recipe and 3 eggs in another will become 5 eggs in the shopping list).

Feel free to use it if it fits your needs.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "drag the recipe" are you referring to a recipe that is already on your site or any recipe on the web (aka, dragging the link to the page with the recipe)?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: A recipe already on the site. If it's not there yet, you'll need to add it. If you don't want anyone else to see the recipe, you can add it as a draft.

Comment: Unfortunately, this link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Pepperplate http://pepperplate.com has a web site, which is great for collecting recipes and they also have both iPhone and iPad apps. iPhone app is convenient when shopping, iPad app when actually cooking.

I was about to implement something like Pepperplate myself, but then found them and been happy so far. There is some annoying bugs in apps, but I hope they get them sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

There is an iPhone app in Australia that may be as close as you want.

http://www.coles.com.au/Stores-Services/Coles-shopmate.aspx

It's not 100% what you are after, but have a look at it as reference.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Paprikia: http://www.paprikaapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of developing a new web app that'll do just this. I'd love to talk to you about features you'd like. If you're still looking for something feel free to contact me at @adammckerlie on twitter.

Answer (score 0):

I built a site that does exactly what you're asking for:

http://mealfire.com

There's no nutritional data, but everything else you've mentioned is there. Actually, you're paragraph is a pretty good description of the core features of the site!

Answer (score 0):

I like http://shopglider.com/

It is web-based, pretty simple: you keep shopping lists and recipes there, can share account between multiple people. Then you decide what to buy next time and plan trip to shops.

They also have Windows Phone app that synchronizes with the web site - so one account user can add more stuff while another it shopping :), but no iPhone or Android app (at least yet).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [CookDiary](http://www.yourcookdiary.com) is to your taste. ;) It does everything you want with the exception of calories calculation (at the moment).

The program is written by me so ask away if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

By chance I had the same question today and installed Gourmet Recipe Manager. Available for Windows and Linux.

"Gourmet Recipe Manager is an application to store, organize and search recipes. Gourmet also makes it easy to create shopping lists from recipes. Gourmet imports recipes from a number of sources, including MealMaster and MasterCook archives and several popular websites. Gourmet can export recipes as text, MealMaster files, HTML web pages, and a custom XML format for exchange with other Gourmet users. Gourmet supports linking images with recipes. Gourmet can also calculate nutritional information for recipes based on the ingredients."

http://grecipe-manager.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to **[HipRecipes.com](https://HipRecipes.com)**:

- It is a web app, **completely free**
- You can **search for recipes** and add them to your basket
- And the app **assemble a grocery list for you**, organised by categories!