# meal planning software with collaboration and sharing

Tags: menu-planning, organization, software

Me and my wife are technophiles. We've had a fair amount of success organizing aspects of our life using [RememberTheMilk](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/) for lists and google calendar for a shared calendar.

Recently we've wanted to up our cooking game (cooking more at home and trying out Primal Blueprint).

What I'm looking for is software that allows us to build a database of recopies (that we share) and meal plans we can collaborate on.

So far I've tried [Pepper Plate](http://www.pepperplate.com/) and I've glanced at all the option in [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10651/looking-for-meal-planning-grocery-list-software). It looks like there are lots of nice options for collecting recipes, a couple that let you share your library with others (not just individual recipes), some (like PepperPlate) have tools to build a meal plan, but what I really want to be able to do is collaborate on meal plans with other people.

Does anyone know of any software that makes this easy? I'd accept "non-meal plan" specific software as long as it works well.

As a bonus the software would be able to put grocery list items in an [RTM](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/home/jachin.rupe/) list and display the meal plan in other calendar software, abut that might be hoping for too much.

Comment: Ziplist doesn't work for this, it advertises a bunch of sharing options but ends up only sharing grocery lists, not meal plans or recipes. We were very disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Paprika](http://paprikaapp.com/) for recipe database, meal planning, and creating shopping lists. You could both log in as the same user and so your recipes, plans and lists would sync between any instances of the application you use. The software also categorizes your grocery items into 'isles' so hopefully it'll be in a logical order when you get to the supermarket.

I have found the software to be very reliable and the developer is very approachable if you do have any issues or feature requests.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to **[HipRecipes.com](https://HipRecipes.com)**:

- You can **create** your own recipes, or **use the ones created by others**
- It is a web app, **completely free**
- To create your weekly meals only takes a few clicks: add the recipes to your basket
- And the app **assemble a grocery list for you**, organised by categories to make shopping easy!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you own the site? We appreciate the disclosure if there's an affiliation.